# Header manipulation not working with fancyhdr package

Tags: header-footer

The default `plain` pagestyle makes an empty header and footer except for the bottom page number. I am trying to amend some text in the header of it (since `plain` is default, this should effect all pages).

I have therefore dug into the `fancyhdr` package. It's [documentation](http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.pdf) (page 8, top) gives this example code to redefine a pagestyle:

> [...] fancyhdr gives you an easier way [to redefine the plain pagestyle] with the `\fancypagestyle` command. This command can be used to redefine existing pagestyles (like plain) or to define new ones, e.g.  **if part of your document is to use a different pagestyle**.  This command has two parameters:  one is the name of the pagestyle to be defined, the second consists of commands that change the headers and/or footers, i.e.
>   fancyhead etc.

```
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
\fancyfoot[C]{\textbf{\thepage}} % except the center
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}}
```

What I have emphasized in **bold** in the quote is exactly my goal. I wish to have a specific word in the header on only a part of the document; a certain range of pages.

But I just can't make this work - not even this example code they give. Here is a clean example code (in [ShareLatex for a live demo](https://www.sharelatex.com/project/58e4e28a54b8ca05149425b0)):

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}  
\usepackage{lipsum}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
\fancyfoot[C]{\textbf{\thepage}} % except the center
\fancyhead[C]{test text} % added text in header
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum 
\lipsum
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

This code chunk makes no change. I have copy-pasted the documentation code example and only added the line: `\fancyhead[C]{test text}`. It doesn't work with or without my extra line. No change.

I can't find the place I am misreading in the documentation. The explanation seems pretty simple. Can anyone point out the mistake?

Comment: @campa: Yes, I figured that out too in the meantime :D Thanks. The change of `plain` is not used unless `\pagestyle{plain}` is used again

Comment: Thanks @campa. It works, but I do get a warning, though, when adding this: "*Package Fancyhdr Warning: \headheight is too small (12.0pt): Make it at least 13.59999pt. We now make it that large for the rest of the document. This may cause the page layout to be inconsistent, however.*" Can this be solved in a quick fix?

Comment: @Steeven: `\usepackage[headheight=14pt]{geometry}`, because you have content in the header that has a larger height than the designed spacing for that.

Comment: @campa: Perhaps this is duplicate, if not, you should transfer your comment into an answer, in my point of view

Comment: Well that was fast and perfect. Yes, @campa, if you will add the answer, I will accept. Thank you both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the last things `article.cls` does is to issue

```
\pagestyle{plain}
```

and this sets the page style to the *current* version of `plain`.
Redefining `plain` in the preamble is therefore not enough, and you need to call `\pagestyle` again

```
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
% WHATEVER
}
\pagestyle{plain}
```

This isn't mentioned in the documentation of `fancyhdr` since (I guess) the example is about redefining `plain` for `\chapter`s, which do call `\thispagestyle{empty}` anyway.

The warning about `\headheight` is not related to this, but as Christian has pointed out in his comment you can solve it by using

```
\usepackage[headheight=14pt]{geometry}
```

Answer (score 3):

As an add-on, I mention `fancyhdr` is not the only package for (re)defining page styles. You also have `titleps`, which comes with `titlesec`, but can be loaded independently, and is simpler to use (it hides the `mark` mechanism). If you load `titlesec`, you just have to set the option `[pagestyles]`.

Here's how it goes:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{titleps}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\renewpagestyle{plain}{%
\sethead{}{Test text}{}
\setfoot{}{\thepage}{}
}%

\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}

\lipsum
\lipsum
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for this extra note. Can this be used to define headers of only certain ranges of pages, as by actual goal was?

Comment: I think so, but not specifying a range in the code. It allows to define new page styles, and it's up to you to decide when and where (well, after a chapter or a part, of course!)  to apply them. So where you want to apply a new page style, you write `\page style{mynicepage style}`. Then  later you can have a `\pagestyle{some-other-page-style}`.